# Replace current items using Owl Carousel 2

Tags: owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

How is it possible to replace/rebuild `owl carousel` items with a new one?

## Description

In many cases, like when you are getting new data from a database you would to add new data in your carousel, but in this example I try to replace all items with a new one.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Old 1-1</h4></div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Old 2-1</h4></div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Old 3-1</h4></div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>Old 4-1</h4></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Owl Carousel 2 documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html), you can use the `replace.owl.carousel` event.

## replace.owl.carousel

Type: `triggerable`
Parameter: `data`

> Removes current content and add a new one passed in the parameter.

## Usage

First you need to use `replace` trigger then append new data with `refresh` trigger. Do not use `destroy` or `re-initialize`

**Example 1** / *Update/Replace*

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true
});

$('#reb').click(function() {
  var html = '<div class="owl-item"><h4>1-2</h4></div><div class="item"><h4>2-2</h4></div><div class="item"><h4>3-2</h4></div><div class="item"><h4>4-2</h4></div><div class="item"><h4>2-2</h4></div>';
  $('.owl-carousel').trigger('replace.owl.carousel', html).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 1-1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 2-1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 3-1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 4-1</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<a id="reb" class="btn btn-success">Rebuild</a>
```

**Example 2** / *Update/Add*

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true
});

$('#reb').click(function() {
  var html = '<h4>New item</h4>';
  $('.owl-carousel').trigger('add.owl.carousel', html).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 1-1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 2-1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 3-1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>Old 4-1</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<a id="reb" class="btn btn-success">Add</a>
```